# How to use add-type with -path and also -language csharpversion3?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've been using add-type in Powershell to dynamically compile in some C# classes I want to use. Works great except it's 2.0 only.

I just discovered the `-language csharpversion3` option, but it does not work with `-path`. How can I work around this?

[Edit: removed bit about ReadAllText - I was mistaken.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the workaround: read the file as text.

```
$script = [io.file]::readalltext($scriptpath)
add-type $script -lang csharpversion3
```

I might as well paste in the rest and make this answer useful in some way.. I have a debug flag that lets me generate the DLL so I can more easily break in with the debugger, inspect it with Reflector, etc.

```
$cp = new-object codedom.compiler.compilerparameters
$cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add('system.dll') > $null
$cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add('system.core.dll') > $null

# optionally turn on debugging support
if ($debugscript)
{
    # delete old unused crap while we're at it
    dir "$($env:temp)\-*.dll" |%{
        del $_ -ea silentlycontinue
        if ($?) { del $_.fullname.replace('.dll', '.pdb') -ea silentlycontinue }
    }

    $cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = $true
    $cp.IncludeDebugInformation = $true
    $cp.OutputAssembly = $env:temp + '\-' + [diagnostics.process]::getcurrentprocess().id + '.dll'
}

$script = [io.file]::readalltext($scriptpath)
add-type $script -lang csharpversion3 -compilerparam $cp
```

This adds some additional functionality if $debugscript is set to true:

- Compile with warnings as errors
- Generate a PDB
- Use a specific DLL/PDB name (in the temp folder) that is tied to the process ID so each session gets its own. This is good for iterating on changes to the .cs.
- Deletes the old dll's and pdb's, also good when iterating.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it exactly what you need, but you can enable .NET 4 support in powershell. Remember that by default it use .NET 2. To do this you need to add in $PSHome an XML with this name powershell.exe.config and this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
        <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
                <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
                <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
        </startup>
</configuration>
```

After that any code targeted to a bigger .net version will work, for example look this:

```
Slytherin>> gc new.cs
using System.IO;

public static class testeo
{
        public static string joinP(string[] arr)
        {
                return Path.Combine(arr);
        }
}
Slytherin>> $arr = "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco"
Slytherin>> Add-Type -Path .\new.cs
Slytherin>> [testeo]::joinP($arr)
uno\dos\tres\cuatro\cinco
```

That method use Path.Combine with N arguments that is defined in .NET4. In .NET2 Combine can only handle up to two arguments. I test other example that use anonymous delegates, one of the characteristics of C#3:

```
Slytherin>> $sharp = [IO.file]::readalltext((resolve-path new.cs))
Slytherin>> add-type  -typedef $sharp -Language CsharpVersion3
Slytherin>> gc .\new.cs
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace grantest
{

public static class testeo
{
        public static void joinP(string[] arr)
        {
                arr.ToList<string>().ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));

        }
}
}
Slytherin>> [grantest.testeo]::joinP($arr)
uno
dos
tres
cuatro
cinco
Slytherin>>
```

One last example if you try the next code it doesn't going to work

```
Slytherin>> $sharp = [IO.file]::readalltext((resolve-path new.cs))
Slytherin>> $sharp
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace grantest
{

public static class testeo4
{
        public static string joinP(string[] arr)
        {
                arr.ToList<string>().ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
                return Path.Combine(arr);
        }
}
}
Slytherin>> Add-Type -TypeDefinition $sharp
Add-Type : c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\5ikkmpfn.0.cs(3) : The type or namesp
ace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly
reference?)
c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\5ikkmpfn.0.cs(2) : using System;
c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\5ikkmpfn.0.cs(3) : >>> using System.Linq;
c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\5ikkmpfn.0.cs(4) :
At line:1 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<<  -TypeDefinition $sharp
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\voodoo...bly reference?):Compile
   rError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType
   Command
```

other try specifying the language parameter

```
Slytherin>> add-type -TypeDefinition $sharp -Language CSharpVersion3
Add-Type : c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\v3r5whoc.0.cs(13) : No overload for m
ethod 'Combine' takes '1' arguments
c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\v3r5whoc.0.cs(12) :         arr.ToList<string>()
.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\v3r5whoc.0.cs(13) : >>>         return Path.Comb
ine(arr);
c:\Users\voodoomsr\AppData\Local\Temp\v3r5whoc.0.cs(14) :     }
At line:1 char:9
+ add-type <<<<  -TypeDefinition $sharp -Language CSharpVersion3
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\voodoo...s '1' arguments:Compile
   rError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType
   Command
```

This is happen because where using a method of .net4 and apparently if you say that the language is version 3 automatically use .net 3 libraries . In order to make this work you need to add System.Core as referenced assembly and forget about the language parameter(the enumeration of possible values doesn't have Csharpversion4) so its going to use the 4 version, because we enable it before.

```
Slytherin>> Add-Type -TypeDefinition $sharp -ReferencedAssemblies System.core
Slytherin>> [grantest.testeo4]::joinP($arr)
uno
dos
tres
cuatro
cinco
uno\dos\tres\cuatro\cinco
```

Good luck, and happy coding.

Comment: Yup, I have my own Powershell configured to support 4.0. It's not really portable though. I can't require everyone here who uses my script has their local Powershell hacked. Not to mention turning on 4.0 support slows down startup time significantly. Thanks for the answer but I think my princess is in another castle.

Comment: yea it slow down incredibly for that reason I have 2 powershell executables, one configured with 2runtime and one with 4runtime. I use the 4 when i'm developing and need to test and play with code and version 2 when i need to run some 2runtime script fast. Just copy the executable and name it for example powershell2.exe, for that executable create the powershell2.exe.config with only the 2 runtime enabled,:)