# Powershell.exe - Unable to compile C# code that uses var

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have the following powershell script:

```
# C-Sharp source for taking our screenshot
$Source = @" 
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Testing
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static void DoTest()
        {
             var myLinq = "hello world";
        }
    }
}
"@

$assem = @("System.Core")
$null = Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language Csharp
```

If I run this via powershell.exe `powershell.exe C:\test.ps1` I get the following error:

```
Cannot add type. There were compilation errors. c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\c9er05ba.0.cs(10) : The type or n
amespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\c9er05ba.0.cs(9) :         {

c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\c9er05ba.0.cs(10) : >>>              var myLinq = "hello world";

c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\c9er05ba.0.cs(11) :   }
```

However, if I copy and paste this script into [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) it runs just fine.

The closest link I could find that was helpful was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475122/how-to-use-add-type-with-path-and-also-language-csharpversion3) one. So I tried changing my -language parameter to be csharpversion3, but now I get this:

```
Cannot add type. There were compilation errors. (0) : An assembly with the same identity 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Cul
ture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

(1) : using System;
```

Any ideas how I can get this script to run properly?

Comment: See Christian's comments on the config file you need for PowerShell to use the .Net v4 runtime. With those options (which I always use) your code compiles __without__ the `-Language` set to `CSharpVersion3`, though you do need to use the variable `myLinq` to avoid a compiler warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick with the `-language csharpversion3` but drop the `-ReferencedAssemblies $assem` bit - that's what's giving you the duplicate import.

I also had to add `-IgnoreWarnings` to get your fragment to compile, but I guess that's because you're not posting the whole example.

In summary, the command:

```
Add-Type  -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CsharpVersion3 -IgnoreWarnings
```

will compile that code without error.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect. So it seems that specifying -language CSharpVersion3 causes it to automatically import those libraries, so I was causing duplicates. Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

This work on Powershell V 2.0 using the powershell.exe.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
      <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
          <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      </startup>
</configuration>
```

Powershell code:

```
$Source = @" 
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Testing
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static void DoTest()
        {
             var myLinq = "hello world";
             Console.WriteLine(myLinq.ToString());
    }
    }
}
"@

$null = Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies system.core -TypeDefinition $Source -Language Csharp
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure Powershell understand the usage of 'var'. Replace your code as follows;

```
string myLinq = "hello world";
```

and see how you get on.

Comment: I'm positive that would work, but isn't Add-Type just trying to compile the C# code into a usable assembly? Shouldn't that be independent of powershell? I guess I would just like a better understanding of why that wouldn't work.